# Memory Management in a Block Using Notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c

According to the Xcode instruments, my code has a memory leak (at #3). But I get the feeling I'm missing something in my mental model of what's going on, so I have a few questions about the following logic:

```
__block MyType *blockObject = object; //1
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if ([self.selectedObjects containsObject:blockObject]) { //2
            [self.selectedObjects removeObject:blockObject];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:ObjectDeselectionNotification object:blockObject]; //3
        } else {
            [self.selectedObjects addObject:blockCart];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:ObjectSelectionNotification object:blockCart];
    }
});
```

1) I'm using a __block reference because I'm executing this code async and don't want a reference to this variable copied to the heap. Is this a valid usage of __block even though I'm not mutating the variable?

2) Calling self.selectedObjects will create a retain on *self*. Does the block automatically release this after it has exited?

3) I apparently have a leak at this point, but I'm not exactly sure why. Is NotificationCenter retaining my __block object that is supposed to be disposed of after my block exits?

Comment: The usual cause of a memory leak in conneciton with notifications is the use of an observer and block to _receive_ the notification. Please show that, if that is what you're doing. Explained here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_unusual_memory_management_situations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you've shown, I don't see any problems...

1) Your object would not be "copied" onto the heap - it is already on the heap being an alloc'd object. Rather, it's reference count would be incremented by 1 as it is now owned by the block. You do not need the __block reference as you are not assigning anything to the pointer. In fact, you do not need blockObject at all and can just pass object.

2.) self should be released once the block is done. However, post a notification is synchronous (this block will not finish until all the objects responding to the notification are done).

3.) I'm not sure what the exact implementation that NSNotificationCenter uses, but it doesn't really matter because the posting is synchronous. It will call every observer of your notification and the selectors they want to receive your notification on

It seems as though you are running all this code within another block - can you paste the full method?

Comment: The code in this block is the full contents of a method. What you see is obviously rather simple, but the consumers of these notifications do take a non-trivial amount of time to process.

Comment: Well, this block won't finish and release its hold on object (or blockObject) until all those observers finish doing what they need to. If you want, you can put an NSLog(...) after the NSNotification lines to see if they have returned while you are checking for leaks. Another option is to wrap the code in your block with an @autoreleasepool {} block to make sure block object is released.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove this answer if incorrect (you've already accepted) but I'm not sure you accepted because the answer worked for you.

I don't think you should be referencing `self` in that block - you will be creating a retain cycle.

```
__weak YourClass *weakSelf = self;
```

use weakSelf instead and cut the tie between the creator and the block floating on the dispatch queue?

Comment: I do not believe there is a retain cycle in his code. The block is not being retained by the class at all. It is sent to the dispatch_queue asynchronously.